# Android populate and set values from UI to object and Viceversa

Tags: android, user-interface, 2-way-object-databinding

I am writing a commercial Android app to take survey, which should also give option to edit survey.
What is the best approach to link UI fields to database without writing explicit logic to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of much in the way of data-binding frameworks for Java at this time. Sorry!